# grep specific variable from output and replace value with another linux

Tags: shell, awk, grep, nfs

I'm trying to get the name of a variable between two different symbols in bash with the following command:

```
nfs4_getfacl .| grep -E ":.:.*:"
```

These are the strings obtained:

```
A:fdg:user@server:rxtTncC
A:g:user@server:xtcy
A:d:1111:xtcy
```

I'm trying to replace the value 1111 or any other numerical values that I come across in the list, this usually comes across as the third position according to the nfs4 permissions but is not always necessarily the case:

*1111* -> *replaced_value*

```
A:fdg:user@server:rxtTncC
A:g:user@server:xtcy
A:d:replaced_value:xtcy
```

Comment: Is it going to be always 3rd line where you want to replce? If not then kindly do mention what are the conditions to apply new variable on lines?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I've updated the question, sorry about the mixup

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your shown samples, please ty following. You could do this in a single `awk` itself, we need not to use grep here. Set `newValue` variable's value as per your need and it will replace value accordingly then.

```
nfs4_getfacl .| 
awk -v newValue="newVALUE" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} /:.:.*:/ && $3~/^[0-9]+$/{$3=newValue} 1'
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk -v newValue="newVALUE" '  ##Getting nfs4_getfacl output as input to awk program, creating newValue variable which has new value in it.
BEGIN{ FS=OFS=":" }           ##Setting field separator and output field separator as : here.
/:.:.*:/ && $3~/^[0-9]+$/{    ##Check if line contains :.:.*: format AND 3rd column is digits.
  $3=newValue                 ##Then set newValue value to 3rd column here.
}
1                             ##printing edited/non-edited lines here.
'
```

Comment: I have a question, would it be possible to save the nfs4 values to a new text file, edit there and save? maybe something like this? nfs4_getfacl . > facl_list.txt | `awk -v newValue="newVALUE" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} /:.:.*:/ && $3~/^[0-9]+$/{$3=newValue} 1' | > new_facl_list.txt`

Comment: An additional comment, I need to replace more than a third row, unfortunately, is that why the `$3` is present? sorry, I'm still getting used to bash scripting, thus my naive questions.

Comment: @Joe_Informatics, sure why not, in that case run program like: `awk -v newValue="newVALUE" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} /:.:.*:/ && $3~/^[0-9]+$/{$3=newValue} 1' facl_list.txt` This should be Good to give you output, cheers.

Comment: @Joe_Informatics, This will replace it in ANY ROW not only in 3rd row. But it will always look for 3rd field/column, try it out once and let me know then.

Comment: @Joe_Informatics, I have also added detailed explanation in my answer for better understanding.

Comment: Thanks, will test now and follow up for any additional questions, really appreciate the help!

Comment: @Joe_Informatics, our welcome, cheers and happy learning.

Comment: sorry to bother you again, do you think it is possible to loop through every directory and apply this command as above?

Comment: @Joe_Informatics, No problem. I would like to request you to open a new question, with all details and your efforts and we could discuss it there, if I could help, I will definitely help, cheers.

Comment: @RavnderSingh13 thanks again, just updated and edited question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68394717/trying-to-execute-command-to-every-directory-with-for-loop