# trying to execute command to every directory with for loop

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop

I'm trying to run a for loop so it will save a file under the basename of the directory and save a specific file in every directory. The bash script does run but it does not save the file:

```
#Obtain ACL list of current working directory
for dir in $CURRENT_DIRECTORY/*; do
    if [ -d "$dir" ]; then
        # Will not run if no directories are available
        echo "$dir"
        #Save basename for the current directory
        FOLDERBASE=$(basename -- "$CURRENT_DIRECTORY")
        #Get current facl
        nfs4_getfacl "$dir" > "$dir"/"$FOLDERBASE"_original.facl
        # Replace current .facl numerical values with correct mapped id and create new facl_list
        awk -v newValue="NEWVALUE" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} /:.:.*:/ && $3~/^[0-9]+$/{$3=newValue} 1' "$CURRENT_DIRECTORY"/"$FOLDERBASE"_original.facl > "$CURRENT_DIRECTORY"/"$FOLDERBASE"_mapped.facl
        # Set the new facl in place
        nfs4_setfacl -S "$CURRENT_DIRECTORY"/"$FOLDERBASE"_mapped.facl "$CURRENT_DIRECTORY"
        echo "Directory access control lists have been modified" 
    fi
done
```

Comment: `CURRENT_DIRECTORY` is a single path; are you trying to iterate over the *subdirectories* under that path?

Comment: Can you try executing the command with `bash -x yourscript`. That will give some more information on the output what exactly is happening

Comment: That would be something like `for d in $PWD/*/; do`. (No need to run `pwd`, and the trailing `/` ensures the pattern only matches directories.)

Comment: @chepner yes I'm trying to also iterate through the subdirectories and save the _copy.acl file to each one of these subdirectories as I will need to use them subsequently

Comment: @chepner the /*/ sticks to one directory, updated the question

Comment: That's because the output of `pwd` doesn't end with a `/`: `$CURRENT_DIRECTORY/*`.

Comment: @chepner the file created is the same for every subdirectory unfortunately, made an update to the question

Comment: you are using $CURRENT_DIRECTORY within your loop, therefore the loop doesn't make sense. $dir is what you need